# How do I set the floating point precision in Perl?

Tags: perl, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Is there a way to set a Perl script's floating point precision (to 3 digits), without having to change it specifically for every variable?

Something similar to TCL's:

```
global tcl_precision
set tcl_precision 3
```

Comment: Do you want only three digits, or three digits after the decimal? There's a difference :)

Comment: is there a way to do any of them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no way to globally change this.

If it is just for display purposes then use `sprintf("%.3f", $value);`.

For mathematical purposes, use `(int(($value * 1000.0) + 0.5) / 1000.0)`.  This would work for positive numbers. You would need to change it to work with negative numbers though.

Comment: If it's just for display purposes then set `$#='%.3f'` -- see `perldoc perlvar`

Comment: `$#` is removed in Perl 5.10 :(

Comment: @SinanÜnür no, you cant! Example: `perl -E'$_ = 155; say sprintf("%.2f", $_/1000);'` Should print `0.16` but prints `0.15`. (see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24493228/734304)

Comment: @SinanÜnür ;) I (now) understand a little bit more about the floating point representation. I commented your comment, because the statement _you can use _sprintf("%.3f", $value) for mathematical purposes too_ is simply not true (is some cases).  I think, than most of the beginner perl programmers (counted me an month ago) thinks than perl could give an "good result" for 2 digits precision - especially, when an perl-expert (you) said - it is possible to use... :) :)

Answer (score 22):

Use [`Math::BigFloat`](https://perldoc.pl/Math::BigFloat) or [`bignum`](https://perldoc.pl/bignum):

```
use Math::BigFloat;
Math::BigFloat->precision(-3);

my $x = Math::BigFloat->new(1.123566);
my $y = Math::BigFloat->new(3.333333);
```

Or with `bignum` instead do:

```
use bignum ( p => -3 );
my $x = 1.123566;
my $y = 3.333333;
```

Then in both cases:

```
say $x;       # => 1.124
say $y;       # => 3.333
say $x + $y;  # => 4.457
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend to use sprintf("%.3f", $value).

Please look at the following example:
(6.02*1.25 = 7.525)

`printf("%.2f", 6.02 * 1.25) = 7.52`

`printf("%.2f", 7.525) = 7.53`

Answer (score 1):

Treat the result as a string and use [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#substr-EXPR%2COFFSET%2CLENGTH%2CREPLACEMENT). Like this:

```
$result = substr($result,0,3);
```

If you want to do rounding, do it as string too. Just get the next character and decide.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the following to truncate whatever comes after the third digit after the decimal point:

```
if ($val =~ m/([-]?[\d]*\.[\d]{3})/) {
    $val = $1;  
}
```