# How can I set the level of precision for Perl's bignum?

Tags: perl, precision, bignum

I'm trying to use the bignum module in Perl and want to set the precision.  I know this can be done via a one liner as detailed on the [module's CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/bignum-0.23/lib/bignum.pm#Options):

```
$ perl -Mbignum=p,-50 -le 'print sqrt(20)'
```

...which will print out the square root of 20 to 50 digits of precision, but what I'm wondering is if there's anyway to set the precision within a script, i.e. something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use bignum;

setPrecision(-50);
print sqrt(20);
```

I've searched around here, Google, and PerlMonks without any luck so far.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specify it as an argument to the package in the `use bignum` line.

Comment: See `perldoc perlrun`; `perl -MPackage=foo,bar` is equivalent to starting the program with `use Package qw(foo bar)`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838808/how-do-i-set-the-floating-point-precision-in-perl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per Anon.'s suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use bignum ( p => -50 );

print sqrt(20);
```

You might like to look at the docs for [Math::BigFloat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::BigFloat) and [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::BigInt) which bignum makes use of.

Comment: That does not work for me, Perl is wrong here:
`perl -e 'use bignum(p=>-100);printf("%1.50f\n",sqrt(23));'` outputs
`4.79583152331271911350540904095396399497985839843750`
This is right:
`perl -Mbignum=p,-50 -le 'print sqrt(23)'`
`4.79583152331271954159743806416269391999670704190413`
compared with the correct calculation from bc:
`echo "scale=50;sqrt(23)"|bc`
`4.79583152331271954159743806416269391999670704190412`